Path resolution from the current directory
I have a file that loads other files from a specified directory:
const dir = path.resolve('./bar')
const dirents = await readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true })

This happens as the result of a function call that can be called from anywhere. For example, given the following tree:
- loader.ts

- foo
  - index.ts
  - bar
    - file.ts

index.ts is the script that is executed (from the root using npx tsx foo/index.ts)
It contains the following code
import loader from '../loader'

loader('./bar')

loader.ts resolves the paths and contains
import path from "node:path";

export default async (dir: string) => {
  const resolved = path.resolve(dir)
  console.log('RESOLVED TO', resolved)
}


The problem is that resolved is resolved to /bar. Directory bar at the root of the project. I've lost the context of foo here.
I've read about import.meta but dirname and filename there only relate to the current file.
This is a basic TypeScript project, no webpack/babel etc.
TL;DR I need to resolve a relative path, not from the current file, but from the file that called it (index.ts)

What happens if you pass __dirname from index.ts as a parameter for loader

This is an ESM module, so __dirname doesn't exist. I'd also like to prevent having to pass the current directory/file as an argument as this will be a module hosted on NPM for others to use, hence the need to get the directory relative to the calling file

In the other question linked in the dupe flag, check out the second answer with caller-callsite

That dup seems to lead me in the right direction. Thanks
